# Foreach loop adding last result onto next

Tags: php, xml, loops, foreach

I have been experimenting with SimplXML to parse out some specific information from a very large XML document to create a new simplified one. I am working with products and the products have variations (like size for instance) that I am trying to build into the array. Some testing is showing that the variation loop is adding the last results onto the next. For instance:

First loop shows this, which is correct for the first product which has 2 variations.

```
["variations"]=>
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["sku"]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#19 (1) {
      [0]=>
      string(8) "00090011"
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    ["sku"]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#19 (1) {
      [0]=>
      string(8) "00090012"
    }
  }
}
```

Now the second product in the loop ends up containing the last loops results and adds it before it's own results.

```
    ["variations"]=>
    array(4) {
      [0]=>
      array(1) {
        ["sku"]=>
        object(SimpleXMLElement)#19 (1) {
          [0]=>
          string(8) "00090011"
        }
      }
      [1]=>
      array(1) {
        ["sku"]=>
        object(SimpleXMLElement)#19 (1) {
          [0]=>
          string(8) "00090012"
        }
      }
      [3]=>
      array(1) {
        ["sku"]=>
        object(SimpleXMLElement)#19 (1) {
          [0]=>
          string(8) "00090013"
        }
      }
      [4]=>
      array(1) {
        ["sku"]=>
        object(SimpleXMLElement)#19 (1) {
          [0]=>
          string(8) "00090014"
        }
      }
    }
```

As you can imagine, this ends up resulting in memory errors and a giant new XML file being created at the end since it's prepends everything before it. Here is my PHP code doing the loop.

```
foreach($data as $element)
{

        if ($element->Dir_Name == "Fly Fishing"){
            //assign element nodes to variables
            $name = $element->PF_Name;
            $id = $element->PF_ID;
            $description = $element->PF_Description;
            $brand = $element->Manufacturer_Brand;
            $image = $element->ImageURL;
            $category1 = $element->Dir_Name;
            $category2 = $element->Group_Name;
            $category3 = $element->Cat_Name;

            //pull in variations
            $item_data = $element->Item;
            foreach($item_data->Sku as $variation){
                $optionName = $variation->Sku_Name;
                $price = $variation->Regular_Price;
                $sku =  $variation->Item_Code;

                $variation_array[] = array(
                    "optionName" => $optionName,
                    "price" => $price,
                    "sku" => $sku
                );
            }
            $products_array[] = array(
                "name" => $name,
                "description" => $description,
                "brand" => $brand,
                "image" => $image,
                "category1" => $category1,
                "category2" => $category2,
                "category3" => $category3,
                "variations" => $variation_array
            );
        }

}
```

I read something about using unset() to try and correct this but it didn't work out. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reset the var `$variation_array` on each loop of `$data` to avoid it building throughout each loop.

You can either redeclare it as an empty array, or unset the var:

```
$variation_array = array();
```

Or

```
unset($variation_array);
```

Full code:

```
foreach($data as $element)
{
    if ($element->Dir_Name == "Fly Fishing"){
        //assign element nodes to variables
        $name = $element->PF_Name;
        $id = $element->PF_ID;
        $description = $element->PF_Description;
        $brand = $element->Manufacturer_Brand;
        $image = $element->ImageURL;
        $category1 = $element->Dir_Name;
        $category2 = $element->Group_Name;
        $category3 = $element->Cat_Name;
        //pull in variations
        $item_data = $element->Item;
        $variation_array = array();
        foreach($item_data->Sku as $variation){
            $optionName = $variation->Sku_Name;
            $price = $variation->Regular_Price;
            $sku =  $variation->Item_Code;

            $variation_array[] = array(
                "optionName" => $optionName,
                "price" => $price,
                "sku" => $sku
            );
        }
        $products_array[] = array(
            "name" => $name,
            "description" => $description,
            "brand" => $brand,
            "image" => $image,
            "category1" => $category1,
            "category2" => $category2,
            "category3" => $category3,
            "variations" => $variation_array
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent!! Thanks so much, such an easy fix!